# change to decode or

Tags: sql, oracle

i need to change this code to decode or any solution to make sure the result for SELL (-ve value) and BUY (+ve value). and it should be display in 1 row so in my oracle report the column  will be side by side for BUY | SELL.

```
sum(case when (o.tran_qty * o.price) < 0 
then (o.tran_qty * o.price) else 0    end) as sell_t,
sum(case when (o.tran_qty * o.price) > 0 
then (o.tran_qty * o.price) else 0 end) as buy_t,
```

for now in report builder i got this result.
[image]

so i need to merge the client no become one row only. 
full code to get result for picture above.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(decode(substr(o.tran_no,1,1), 'B', 'BUY')) Buy,
COUNT(decode(substr(o.tran_no,1,1),'S', 'SELL')) sell,
nvl('D.EXCH_CODE','01') AS CODE,
sum(case when (o.tran_qty * o.price) < 0 then
   (o.tran_qty * o.price) else   0 end) as sell_t,
sum(case when (o.tran_qty * o.price) > 0 then 
   (o.tran_qty * o.price) else 0 end) as buy_t,
o.client_no,c.client_name,
sum(o.tran_qty*o.price)total,o.branch_code,r.descr,
C.TDR_CODE
from bos_m_ledger o,bos_m_para r,bos_m_client c,
bos_cltype g,BOS_M_STOCK   D
WHERE
r.para_type='BRANCH'
AND R.PARA_CODE = O.BRANCH_CODE
and o.client_no=c.client_no
AND O.STOCK_NO =D.STOCK_NO
AND D.CSTAMP_EXPIRY_DATE IS NOT NULL
AND C.CLIENT_NO='3JF0391'
and g.nbrk_rate=1
and c.client_type=g.client_type
and o.tdr_code=c.tdr_code
and o.tran_type= 'CON'
AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(O.TRAN_DATE,'MON'),'MON')=TO_DATE(:P_MONTH,'MON')
AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(O.TRAN_DATE,'YYYY'),'YYYY') = TO_DATE(:P_YEAR,'YYYY')
group by  
substr(o.tran_no,1,1),o.client_no,o.branch_code,r.descr,c.client_name,
C.TDR_CODE
ORDER BY O.BRANCH_CODE, C.TDR_CODE,O.CLIENT_NO
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help!

Comment: You can try using max(sum... ) with group by on ClientNo, ClientName

Answer (score 0):

Use the following with `decode` :

```
select ClientNo "Client No", 
       ClientName "Client Name", 
       sum(decode(contract_type,'Sell',-tran_qty,tran_qty)) "No_Of_Contract", 
       sum(decode(contract_type,'Sell',-tran_qty * price,tran_qty * price)) "Total" 
  from Sales
 group by ClientNo, ClientName
 order by 1;
```